# Does SSMS support the latest UML version?

Tags: uml, ssms

Does SQL server management studio(SSMS) support the latest UML version?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which version of SSMS are you asking supports which version of UML?

Comment: @DanielGale The latest version of SMSS.

Comment: http://www.drdobbs.com/architecture-and-design/uml-25-do-you-even-care/240163702
According to this site, there is virtually no change in the language in this version. Is there something specific you are trying to do that you cannot do?

Comment: @DanielGale It's just I have been comparing different tools and SSMS was one of them. And some tools only support UML 2.0 and some support UML 2.5. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Does SSMS support any UML at all? Never heard of the combination of SSMS and UML.

Comment: @GeertBellekens SSMS will draw a few diagrams based on the structure of the tables and display their relationships etc. Changes to the diagrams affect the underlying entities/properties. I don't think SSMS is used for UML typically.

Comment: @DanielGale ERD’s are not part of UML

Comment: @GeertBellekens You are correct. ERD is not in the UML standard of diagrams. However there are diagrams such as component diagram that can give a similar visual result to that of an entity-relationship diagram.

Comment: @DanielGale C# and Java also visually look similar, but they still are completely different languages. The same is true for UML and ERD. You might be able to create ERD diagrams with SSMS, but I don't think you can create any UML with it.

Comment: UML is a language. ERD is a diagram. There are specified diagrams in UML that will serve the same purpose whether ERD or UML based diagrams. I doubt SSMS will use the 'standardized' symbols for an ERD or UML diagrams.

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server Management Studio doesn't support UML at all.

You might be able to create ERD's with it but ERD's is not UML.